# Asp.net session management in load balance environment

Tags: asp.net, session, session-management

Any recommendations for transition from single server to load balancing environment of 3 servers?

I considered using Sql Server session management, but I am storing linq2sql objects in session which has serialization issues. With a quick search I found a [workaround](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqsqlserialization.aspx) .But I am skeptical to use this approach considering code-change/readability/performance issues. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: why are you storing linq2sql objects in 'session'? firstly, normally this should be held in cache, secondly, ideally you shouldnt be caching linq2sql objects - either project them into POCO's or into a generic collection (e.g List<T>). If you're worried about serialization, then use ASP.NET State Service on a intermediary box - point all other servers to that (so the session is shared). but of course if that box goes down say goodbye to any current session.

Comment: -These are user/form specific data before users commit them into DB
-All objects are of type Collection<T>. The relation between the objects still persists as they are passed between layers(cause of serialization issue)
-I thought state service does serialization too. May be I am wrong

Comment: you're right, it does do serialization, just speaking from experience ive had troubles with sql state (sessions expiring for no reason).

Comment: @RPM1984, agree with you. I Have had few scars my self with inproc as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a suggestion : Can't you use sticky sessions in your load balancer?

Comment: I am using inproc until now. I don't know how to use sticky sessions in asp.net. Is there a way to access and modify the sessions in load balancer?

Comment: @Syam, This has to be configured at the loadbalancer. We are using this in production with three servers. Most hardware and s/w load balancers are able to do this. see.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)#Persistence

Comment: I just confirmed with network team about the sticky sessions. This solves my issue. Thank a lot

Answer (score 2):

We use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) but it sounds like you want something to be a more critical portion of your app than just caching if you're placing LINQ to SQL objects up there (and I btw agree with RPM that you should consider getting out of that business...)

Anyway, [this is a nice blog post](http://scottw.com/velocity) that gives you a few options.  Velocity is definitely one to look at since it's what Microsoft is offering (this is an asp.net app) and it seems to be gaining steam these days.

Comment: I like this solution but my problem seems to be much simpler than that. @LightX suggested I use sticky sessions for this issue. Thanks a lot any way. As I mentioned, I am using colletion<T> objects to store in the session. The relation between those tables are the once causing serialization pains